# Add 9-patch image to Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, nine-patch

I've created a nine-patch image using the [Simple Nine-Patch Generator](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html). This creates a directory with a `res`-folder, containing folders for each pixel-density-version of the image.

In `Eclipse with ADT` one could simply drag & drop these folders in the `res`-folder of your project.

This would seem like a no-brainer, but how do I add these generated nine-patch images to Android Studio?
I'm using Android Studio 1.0.1.

Comment: right click "copy", then right click "paste"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your problem is that you cant find were the drawables are you could eaisly select pakages from the top left side in the project structure there you can find the res folder and you could eailsy paste the 9 path in the corresponding folders
[image]

Comment: I think i am late... :)

Comment: Early bird gets the worm :) But thanks, I didn't know about this!