# How to place 9patch generated images in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, nine-patch

[image]
[image]

I used the freely available Simple 9patch generator available online, to generate a logo for my app's splash screen. 
But how do I place it in Android Studio drawable folder? 
Do I have to make separate drawable folders like `ldpi`, `hdpi` etc? 
I tried that but when I try to set the image on a layout, it gives me an error saying

```
Cannot resolve symbol @drawable/something
```

[image]

Comment: Some more code you can give?

Comment: I added 2 images to the question '

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure, you have place the images in the correct folder. Here's an example,

[image]

Original post: [Add 9-patch image to Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27501334/add-9-patch-image-to-android-studio)

Comment: don't use .9 after an image in layout, e.g just use "splash" not "splash.9"

Comment: yes , I corrected it in my project, still the same error.

Comment: Do I have to make separate folders if the different folders are not available(ldpi, hdpi etc)?

Comment: Yes. I can see you have created the sub-folders inside the drawable folder which is wrong. Simple change your project view to "packages" and create the folders there.

Comment: Can you post your update folder structure screenshot?

Comment: posted the screenshot to the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84303/discussion-between-prokash-sarkar-and-aman-grover).

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the `.9` in `@drawable/splash.9`. It is just `@drawable/splash`. `.9.png` is the file extension, and file extensions are not used in references to resources.

Comment: even after writing `@drawable/splash` it is still giving me same error